# How do I delete one of my custom templates in Numbers - OS 10.10.1

Tags: mac, macos, numbers

I would like to delete one of my custom templates I made in Numbers - in previous OS versions you went to Library>iWork>Numbers>Templates and just trash it - but, since I updated to Yosemite - I only see Keynote in the iWork Library folder? No Numbers? Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rename or delete a custom template
After you install a template, it appears in the My Templates category in the template chooser.

In the template chooser, Control-click the template name, then choose Rename or Delete.

If you’re renaming, type a new name, then press Return.

You can’t rearrange templates; they always appear in the order in which they were added.

Comment: They always appear in alphabetical order for me.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, you want to press the control button (NOT the command button) then click on the template you want to delete. A little menu will give you the option to delete or rename it. Since this post is about deleting it, you just click on delete, and there you go.

Answer (score -1):

In Pages, you can save the template to Desktop and then move it to Trash.  Maybe it works the same in Numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Right-click or <kbd>Command</kbd> + Click on unwanted template, then delete it.

Comment: answer is relevant to Numbers v3.6.1

Comment: This adds nothing that isn't already said in the upvoted answer [except that your key-command is wrong]